# How to send JSON reply from a jetty endpoint in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, dsl

I'm working on a pass-through REST service in Apache Camel. Exposed an end point with jetty component which invokes another REST end point which responds with JSON like below. But when I hit the exposed URL of Camel in a browser not getting desired output. Since I just started working on Camel, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/camel/appoverview")
        .to("http4://10.150.60.237:80/api/itsb/applicationoverview?httpMethod=GET&bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
        .transform().simple("<out>${body}</out>")
        .log("Response sent -> ${body}");
```

**Getting output -**

```
<out> {
         "applicationId": "1",
         "applicationName": "NetInfo",
         "serviceNoticeCount": "13",
         "operationalStatus": {
            "id": "2",
            "status": "red",
            "statusLevel": "3"
         }
      }
</out>
```

**Desired output -**

```
 {
         "applicationId": "1",
         "applicationName": "NetInfo",
         "serviceNoticeCount": "13",
         "operationalStatus": {
            "id": "2",
            "status": "red",
            "statusLevel": "3"
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked after unmarshalling the JSON reply like below -

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/camel/appoverview")
        .to("http4://10.150.60.237:80/api/itsb/applicationoverview?httpMethod=GET&bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=true")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .transform().simple("${body}")
        .log("Response sent -> ${body}");
```

Dependency for unmarshalling needs to be added in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```